# Spaces of Orders?

Tags: functional-analysis, order-theory

Given some set $\mathcal{X}$, do mathematicians study spaces of "nice" (e.g. archemidean, linear, etc) orders on that set in any way analogous to how spaces of "nice" (e.g. continuous, integrable) functions are studied?

I'm particularly interested in metric spaces of orders.

Comment: Do you mean a space whose points are, say, the linear orders on a set $X$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes.

Comment: There is a particular instance witnessed in the proof of a Set Theory result where one considers a set (not space) of nice orders. If you are interested I can develop it in an answer, although it doesn't address exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @Rick thanks for your interest. I'm mostly interested in a space of orders in order (ha!) to understand things like inner products, metrics, and so on defined on orders as well as properties such as completeness of the induced metric/inner product spaces. Without knowing what you're referencing, my guess would be that considering sets of orders alone may not answer these questions. But I would be overjoyed to be wrong.